# Google Data API - Access Not Configured Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I am using the objective-c google data api library to try and access youtube data. I have set up an app, enabled the youtube data api, and created an ios specific key. However, every time I try to access the api, I get a 403 "access not configured" error. I have quintuple-checked my bundle identifier as well. Here's my code:

```
service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
service.retryEnabled = YES;
service.apiVersion = @"v3";
service.APIKey = @"API KEY GOES HERE";  // proper api key is filled in here

[service executeQuery:query
                            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            id object,
                            NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *videos = object;
        for (GTLYouTubeVideo *video in videos) {
            NSLog(@"%@", video);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

Comment: This issue is reported internally. You can track it through public issue tracker.
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770

Comment: Thanks! Just for the record here, based on your message in the issue tracker, we can get around this by removing the bundle identifier record in the google api console for now. Use with caution, as this can open you up to unauthorized use with your key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in the first comment on this question.